# Refresh expiration time of entry in Infinispan on get

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, cache-invalidation

I've been searching in the docs of infinispan but couldn't find out an easy way to refresh the expiration time of an entry after a get automatically.

Today I'm registering a Listener and, inside the @CacheEntryVisited event, I remove and put it inside again, but it is, of course, not ideal.

```
@CacheEntryVisited
public void entryVisited(CacheEntryVisitedEvent<String, String> event) {
    cache.remove(event.getKey);
    cache.put(event.getKey(), event.getValue(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

There is some kind of config that can be used in CacheManager to make this refresh?

thanks in advance

Comment: TTL is not a standard term with respect to Infinispan.  Are you referring to eviction or expiration?

Comment: expiration.. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable max idle expiration as described at [1]. Also the method you might be looking for is [2] which takes a lifespan and max idle expiration. You can pass -1 for a value which means to not use for expiration.

Also you should be careful when using max idle in clustered caches as it is not guaranteed that other nodes will update their idle access times (if you read was local).

[1] http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#expiration_details

[2] https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/commons/api/BasicCache.html#put-K-V-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: Method [2] seems useful, but I need a combination of the two. Unless I set the lifespan to -1 the maxIdleTime is kinda useless, because the "countdown" of lifespan does not reset when one entry is accessed.

Comment: forget it... using lifespan to -1 and setting the maxIdleTime is exactly what I asked. Thanks!